# Can't see a button under a ListView in my layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's a layout of my Activity XML:

[image]

For some reason I can't see that button t the bottom of my screen.
Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minHeight="44dip"
        android:minWidth="44dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblNotesCount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/lblNotesCountColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTxtNotes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/lblNotesCountColor" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtActivityListByCategory_Header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/color_WHITE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddNote"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_new_note_selector"
        android:minHeight="44dip"
        android:minWidth="44dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:text="@string/txtEmptyList"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/emptyList" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstNotesByCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnaBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnBack" />
```

I tried to put the bottom TextView and ListView in a separate LinearLayout, I tried to give that button a layout_weight - nothing helped, I still don't see that button, the LinearLayout goes till the bottom of the activity.

What is wrong here? Why don't I see that button?

**EDIT: Wrote down the entire XML code**

Comment: can you provide the entire layout xml?

Comment: Try putting layouts in scrollview

Comment: I assume you forgot to copy/paste the closing </LinearLayout> tag? What if you make the button have a static size, like android:layout_height="50dp" and maybe same for the width.

Comment: you can try layout_marginButton = "50dP" for listview.so that buttom will be shown.

Comment: @ lgal Do you mean to add a button to the bottom of the List view,so that if the list grows longer,Button may be placed at the bottom of list

Comment: @deville Edited the question with the entire layout.

Comment: @NickL Actually I did copy/pasted it, but for some reason it doesn't show up here... :-/

Comment: @AndroidKiller Tried it, still couldn't see that button...

Comment: @AnazA No, the button should be there all the time. When the user clicks it - he should return to previous Activity.

Comment: You try to place all views inside one Linear layout.Hope it works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your ListView's `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstNotesByCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnaBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnBack" />
```

This will make your ListView expand vertically till the borders of your Button.

Hope this helps

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you very much! And I was trying to apply android:layout_weight="1" to the button in my previous attempts... Now it works just fine! Thanks again!

Comment: @Murat Nafiz interesting solution, +1 for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fix the height of your ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstNotesByCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="height you want to give to list"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>
```

or

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstNotesByCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:layout_above="@id/btnaBack">
    </ListView>
```

try using this code this will help you

Comment: @Ravinder `android:layout_above` isn't helpful in case of `LinearLayout`

Comment: android:layout_above is not supported in LinearLayout

Comment: then use relative layout, fi you dnt want to use relative layout then try to fix the height of your listview leave space for your button below

Answer (score 1):

1>Use Recycle view with height "wrap content"
 for this link is
https://gist.github.com/AnderWeb/1eb97efb9963171c42bb

2> Put button bellow RecycleView.

Second Solution
Take Relative layout as parent layout
 Add Button and List view on  Relative layout
 Button should parent Bottom true

List View Should above of your  Button

Answer (score 0):

try this it helps you to understand how to use Layou_weight

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:text="txtEmptyListsss"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstNotesByCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="6"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnaBack"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="btnBack" />

  </LinearLayout>
```