# Can't see buttons in Android Activity

Tags: android, button

I can't see buttons at the bottom no matter I tried. There should be a TextView at the top and six buttons beneath it. But somehow, I can't see them. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720746/cant-see-a-button-under-a-listview-in-my-layout), and also [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) but they didn't help. Please tell me, what is the problem? Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux1"
        android:onClick="is_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux2"
        android:onClick="can_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux3"
        android:onClick="must_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux4"
        android:onClick="do_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux5"
        android:onClick="will_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux6"
        android:onClick="has_clicked" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT: Also this is my activity:**

```
public class AuxilaryVerbs extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auxilary);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRAMESSAGE_MAIN);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(30);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);
    }

    public void is_clicked(View view)   {


    }
    public void can_clicked(View view)  {


    }
    public void must_clicked(View view) {


    }
    public void do_clicked(View view)   {


    }
    public void will_clicked(View view) {


    }
    public void has_clicked(View view)  {


    }
}
```

Comment: just tried your XML, I dint see any problems!

Comment: Really? I still experience the same problem. Do you think it is because of my Virtual Device settings or something? I am new to this; so I am sorry for my newbie questions.

Comment: @MertToka I updated answer with right problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse auto xml generator adds a lot of extra attribute that you don't need and when you try to edit it manually you get lost.

First replace RelativeLaout to LinearLayout and make it vertical, it will make it simpler. Then remove all layout_toRightOf,left, below etc attribute and make it simple. Then you will see all your buttons. However if there isn't enough space to show all in your device then you will have to put button in ScrollView so you can scroll and get all buttons.

I tried to update xml (there could be some typos)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux1"
        android:onClick="is_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux2"
        android:onClick="can_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux3"
        android:onClick="must_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux4"
        android:onClick="do_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux5"
        android:onClick="will_clicked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bttn_aux6"
        android:onClick="has_clicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**
Remove this. You are setting your whole view with just this textView. You have already set your view.

```
 setContentView(textView);
```

You have already set layout using following line. You shouldn't overwrite it again.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_auxilary);
```

You already have your textview when you setContentView with your layout file. You can get access to it using following line.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // id of textview from layoutfile
```

and that's it, don't overwrite view.

Comment: I tried this with a phone and a tablet, I can't still see them. Could it be possible that I miss something more fundamental? I can see a button on my MainActivity without doing extra work, should I do something else in another activity to see buttons?

Comment: @MertToka like other people commented that it is working. Try to see if you are including the right layout.xml file in your activity.

Comment: You are right, problem is because of the setContentView line. But without using it, how can I see the textView from the MainActivity in this activity? Can you recommend me something?

Comment: Thank you very much. If you haven't helped me, probably I would have gone crazy right now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to previous declared ids are not correct.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" <---no plus sign; "@id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" <---no plus sign;
    android:text="@string/bttn_aux1"
    android:onClick="is_clicked" />
```

The following fields are having the same problem.

Use plus sign only when you assign an id for the first time, such that it will declare that id. No need to use the plus sign when the id is already declared.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's good to know such stuff. I created the interface using Graphical Layout, so I think Eclipse messed something. But I still have the problem, could it be because of something else?

Comment: @MertToka i don't have problems displaying the buttons too. Perhaps you are just using a emulator device with a too small screen. Try removing `android:layout_marginLeft` on your first button and see if anything appears.

Comment: What is your device's screen dimensions? Or maybe problem is not in the layout, it is in my .java files. Should I do something specific to display buttons in activity file?

Comment: @MertToka in your ADT you can choose to display multiple screen dimensions at the same time. In the toolbar opened when you open a layout XML, second button, choose screen size of your choice. There is a "Preview all screens" option at the bottom.

Comment: @MertToka also do you mind posting your activity if you think java file is causing some problem?

Comment: I edited my question and added the activity. For your previous suggestion, I don't have a problem in Graphical Layout, I can see them. I have problem when I actually run the app in a Virtual Device.